# Can maven resolve the dependency based on higher version

Tags: maven, maven-3

I was exploring archiva as the intenal maven repository manager. I need to manage dependecies.
My application is bundle of modules. I would like to manage dependencies on the basis of higher version.
For eg. Module A uses version 1 of the dependency. While module B uses version 2 of the same dependecy.
Now if a person want to use both the modules then the result should be such that the version two should get referred instead of version 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not a wanted behaviour. What if Version 1 and 2 are incompatible. If you have controll of both Modules A and B than its better to let them use the same version of their dependencies. I Typically declare common dependencies in the parent POM in the dependencyManagement section to so each submodule uses the same version.